# Redirect to route not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, redirect, soap, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have an app where the user submits a form which performs a SOAP exchange to get some data from a Web API.  If there are too many requests in a certain time, the Throttle server denies access.  I have made a custom error view for this called `throttle.blade.php` which is saved under `resources\views\pages`.  In `routes.php` I have named the route as:

```
Route::get('throttle', 'PagesController@throttleError');
```

In `PagesController.php` I have added the relevant function as:

```
public function throttleError() {
    return view('pages.throttle');
}
```

Here is the `SoapWrapper` class I have created to perform the SOAP exchanges:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use SoapClient;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Redirect;

class SoapWrapper {

public function soapExchange() {

    try {
        // set WSDL for authentication
        $auth_url = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl";

        // set WSDL for search
        $search_url = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WokSearch?wsdl";

        // create SOAP Client for authentication
        $auth_client = @new SoapClient($auth_url);

        // create SOAP Client for search
        $search_client = @new SoapClient($search_url);

        // run 'authenticate' method and store as variable
        $auth_response = $auth_client->authenticate();

        // add SID (SessionID) returned from authenticate() to cookie of search client
        $search_client->__setCookie('SID', $auth_response->return);

    } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
        // if it fails due to throttle error, route to relevant view
        return Redirect::route('throttle');
    }
}
}
```

Everything works as it should until I reach the maximum number of requests allowed by the Throttle server, at which point it should display my custom view, but it displays the error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 273:
Route [throttle] not defined.
```

I cannot figure out why it is saying that the Route is not defined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You did not define a name for your route, only a path. You can define your route like this:

```
Route::get('throttle', ['as' => 'throttle', 'uses' => 'PagesController@throttleError']);
```

The first part of the method is the path of the route in your case you defined it like `/throttle`. As a second argument you can pass array with options in which you can specify the unique name of the route (`as`) and the callback (in this case the controller).

You can read more about routes in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing).